# Best practices for SQL Server exception handling in ServiceStack.OrmLite?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ServiceStack.OrmLite with the SQL Server provider.

Given the code fragment below:

1. Is there a best practice for retrieving SQL Server exceptions?
2. What is the best way to know if a record is in the result of the db.Single call ? It seems I get an exception when db.Single is called with an invalid message ID (ie. a message ID that is not in the data set). The call returns without exceptions if  messages IDs exist in the database. Is there a way to do this without the try catch block?

Exception if call is made without try/catch block:

> ArgumentNullException  Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: ENSMessageEntry: 'ID = 25' does not exist

And here is my code:

```
public ENSStatusResponse GetMessageStatus(int messageID)
{
    var statusResponse = new ENSStatusResponse();

    using (var db = DBConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
    {
        try
        { 
            ENSMessageEntry mes = db.Single<ENSMessageEntry>("ID = " + messageID);
            statusResponse.ENSMessageStatus = mes.Id;
        }
        catch  
        {   
            statusResponse.ENSMessageStatus = 0;
        }
    } 

    return statusResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. I don't think this query would generate a SQL Server exception, the exception is coming from `.Single` which is assuming there will be result and throwing if there is not.
2. Use `Db.GetByIdOrDefault<ENSMessageEntry>(messageID)` and check for null

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I realize your point for number one - just wondering if there is a plan to get SQLExceptions through the ORMlite stack.  As for #2... that's what I was looking for, Thanks